Building Qt5 dynamic on Windows
In the past I successfully created Qt5 static builds for windows.
This time I'm trying to build the latest Qt5 as a dynamic build, but the resulting build is not functional, specifically:

if I use it for a QtCreator kit, and use said kit to run my application from within QtCreator, the application crashes at start with an error that it cannot find suitable platform plugin

if I copy all the dlls and the plugins directory into my application build directory and run it from the command prompt, the application still crash at start, this time without any meaningful error message (debugging plugins via envvar shows that all relevant plugins are found).


The configure command I used, before nmake and nmake install, is
C:\Qt5\qt5\bin\release>..\..\configure.bat  -v -release -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests  -platform 
win32-msvc -opengl desktop -openssl -openssl-linked -I C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL_1.1\Win_x64\include -LC:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL_1.1\Win_x64\lib -
recheck-all -skip qtpurchasing -qt-doubleconversion -qt-pcre -qt-zlib -qt-harfbuzz -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-sqlite -
feature-location-labs-plugin -feature-webengine-proprietary-codecs -no-feature-webengine-developer-build -no-feature-
webengine-system-ninja -webengine-jumbo-build 0 

Note: the compilation of both Qt5 and of my app with this Qt5 build succeeds.
Also, note that on the same system the application is successfully built and run using the Qt company's online installer 5.15.2 version through QtCreator.
Update 19.08.24:
I have now tested both a prefix build with a conventional prefix (c:\foo) and a prefix build with -prefix %CD%\qtbase . However, both builds fail in the same way when used from within QtCreator through a kit.
Is there something wrong or missing in my configure line that makes it disfunctional? From what I can tell, i am not using a prefix (does this make a difference? nmake install installs it into C:\Qt\Qt-5.15.14) and the build has no qt.conf as output. But I'm not sure to what extent this affects the build..
Alternately, could someone provide a configure line that would build dynamic Qt5 and run alright on windows(7)?

can you run it under a debugger ? you may have dll hell problem

Related to the above comment: Make sure you are not mixing dlls made with a different compiler meaning Qt binaries built with MinGW are no good for msvc and msvc binaries are no good for MinGW.

I haven't tried debugger as i'm building only release. But i suppose it's a good idea to try! As for mixup, my app depends only on Qt, so i build it with the Qt build produced by the above script, and using the same compiler (msvc)

a debugger will tell you what dlls are being loaded and what code caused you application to crash, this is very useful in tracking why your application crashes.

As I know default compile for Qt is dynamic which means that if you install Qt from installer its dynamic.

Yes, i agree, adding -dynamic is redundant. I have it there for clarity

@AhmedAEK running it through a debugger yield to a "the CDB process terminated" without additional error or leads. That is, using a Qt5 debug build

It just so turns out that my configure line is apparently correct.
However, for whatever reason(1), using the resulting build from within QtCreator kept failing.
Building the application from the command line, instead, using the qmake from that build directory, produces a working binary.
I have no idea how QtCreator gets it wrong (i tried version 4.13, 4.15 and 5.0.3), but at least i have solved my problem and can build the application now.
(1) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html#step-3-set-the-environment-variables
